# Keyword not supported: 'server(local); database'

Tags: asp.net

my web.config is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="taraznegarConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=taraznegar;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and this is my code:

```
namespace taraz
{
    public class DAL
    {
        string connection = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=taraznegar;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        public DAL()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connection;
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand=cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();

        }
        public DataTable ExecuteReader(string SQL)
        {
            connect();
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = SQL;
            try
            {
                da.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch
            {
                da = null;
            }
            disconnect();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
       public string ExcuteNonQuery(string SQL)
        {
            string result=null ;
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            connect();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch { result = "خطا"; }
            disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        public string ExecuteScalare(string sql)
        {
            string result = null;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            connect();
            try { 
                result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch { result = "خطا"; }
            disconnect();
            return result;

        }

        void connect()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
        }
        void disconnect()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

and when I'm using this class in my project the error is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Keyword not supported: 'server(local); database'.

what's the probleam?

Comment: Do you have reference to EntityFramework ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `ConnectionString` in your webconfig file then in your application you don't need to create another connection. You should use that connection. In your class `DAL` you are creating a new connection string. Instead of that you should use something like this-

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["taraznegarConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Entity Framework (database-first or model-first; when you have a physical EDMX model file) you need to use a special type of connection string which is quite different from the straight ADO.NET connection strings everyone else has mentioned so far...

The connection string must look something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="testEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;Initial Catalog=taraznegar;Integrated Security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Inside this connection string, you'll find the `provider connection string=` attribute which is basically your ADO.NET connection string: